# ERROR: opening file <file name> for output when using wav_to_flac + FLACiOS framework for iOS

Tags: ios, swift2, avfoundation, flac

I am trying to convert audio from AVRecorder wav file to flac.  I have added the FLACiOS framework as well as the [wav_to_flac](https://github.com/jhurt/wav_to_flac) helper from [jhurt](https://github.com/jhurt).

I have set my recorder settings to the following:

```
// -------------------------------------------------+
// MARK: - AVFoundation Setup Methods
// -------------------------------------------------+
private func setupRecorder()  {
    let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
            AVSampleRateKey: 16000.0,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue
    ]

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: recordFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    } catch {
        print("Error: attempt to create AVAudioRecorder failed miserably!")
    }
}
// =================================================+
```

I am handling the conversion in the AVRecorderDelegate method as follows:

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    // Delegate housekeeping
    audioRecorderDelegate?.didFinishRecording(recorder.url)
    tempFiles.append(recorder.url)

    // Set up files for flac conversion
    let flacOutFile = (recorder.url.URLByDeletingPathExtension!.absoluteString as NSString).UTF8String
    let flacInFile = (recorder.url.absoluteString as NSString).UTF8String
    let outFiles = flac_file_array()

    // Internal housekeeping for memory freeing later
    outputFileBuffers.append((count: 1024, buffer: outFiles))

    convertWavToFlac(flacInFile, flacOutFile, 0, outFiles)
    recordFileURL = urlGen()
}
```

The wav files play back ok. Jhurt says the convertWavToFlac function expects Apple's undocumented wav format, rather than the "normal" wav. I am not sure if AVAudioRecorder is outputting that given the settings I am providing.

I am providing url to the recorder using a url generator function I wrote that returns a closure that generates a new url:

```
func generateFileURL(withExtension fileExtension: String) -> URLGenerator {
var number = 0
let tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let docPath = tempDir + "tmp"
return { () in
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docPath + "\(number)" + ".\(fileExtension)")
    number += 1
    return url
}
```

}

with the wav extension.  I read in the Audio Programming  that AVAudio infers type from an extension.

I get the following error when I using convertWavToFlac:

```
ERROR: opening file:///Users/ShahtieShack/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/15522B12-9026-44B0-922C-415433D72982/data/Containers/Data/Application/051442B5-639C-4654-8D53-14B245DE7FEB/tmp/tmp0.wav for output
```

I am running this in the simulator and have not gotten the framework to work on a device.  I have searched all around for MODERN answers to this problem.  ANY help would be welcome.

**EDIT:** I have run this app on both the Simulator AND a Device and get the same error.  I am feeding the convertWaveToFlac function audio that I have successfully recorded from the Microphone.

Comment: You seem to be just making up a name that you think the recorded file _should_ have. Look at the recorded file to see what its name and extension _really_ is.

Comment: @matt If you check the line:
`let flacInFile = (recorder.url.absoluteString as NSString).UTF8String `
I am getting the URLdirectly from AVAudioRecorder using the url it just recorded to.

Comment: Also, the path that the error generates leads to a fully working wave file.  It is the same path I use  for playing back the recorded audio in the playback function.  and when running in the simulator I can copy and paste the URL into the terminal and it takes me directly to the recorded file

Comment: Fair enough, but if you're sure of that, then surely this is a question for the author of `wav_to_flac`, yes?

Comment: I was in contact with him the past couple of days.  He can't seem to figure it out either.  He is in Japan right now and his time has been limited but he has tried to throw suggestions that have not panned out.  I'm baffled.  I'm going to attempt to write my own wrapper and see how it goes.  Reading up on Core Audio and any other audio programming resources that may help.